# create custom pdf viewer for iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, pdf

I want to develop a custom pdf viewer, in which I can add features like:

- bookmarks
- jump to specific page
- take some notes
- page flipping effect

Can you suggest some libraries in Cocoa touch to fullfill my requirements?

I followed the [PDF viewing tutorial](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/16552-pdf-viewer-tutorial.html) in which a webview was used but it only provides basic scrolling and zoom facilities. I have seen some apps in which bookmarks and page flipping is possible. Kindly suggest me  something so that I can integrate more features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289186/pdfkit-framework-available-on-the-iphone-os) here on stack overflow will give you some answers.