# Handling PDF content in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

i am using CGPDFDocumentRef to display Pdf document.How can i take the text from pdf to display in different style in UITextview?any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this is an exact duplicate, but this question is related:

[PDFKit framework available on the iPhone OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289186/pdfkit-framework-available-on-the-iphone-os)

In a nutshell, PDFKit isn't part of Cocoa Touch, and AFAIK, CGPDFDocument doesn't do what you want. You'll need a third-party library.